# Coding theory graduate text and programming

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, coding-theory, programming

I begin a PhD in coding theory next fall, and it concerns coding over certain types of rings (e.g. finite chain rings) instead of fields, and in consequence submodule codes. I have a fair amount of knowledge in comm. algebra and have had a standard undergraduate coding theory over finite fields course, so I was wondering:

> Is there a well-respected graduate text, or a good set of notes, covering more advanced tools in algebraic coding theory?

Thanks, and let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Comment: Thanks, edited to remove one question

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for the edit (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following relatively recent book is the only one I know about. Its contents include:

Quasicyclic codes over chain rings

MDR codes

Convolutional Codes over Rings

Shi, Alahmadi and Sole, *Codes and Rings: Theory and Practice*, Academic Press, 2017